# .Net install: Setup may not run properly, because the Windows Update Service is not available on this computer

Tags: wine

> Setup may not run properly, because the Windows Update Service is not available on this computer.
>
> Setup may not run properly, because the Windows Modules Installer Service is not available on this computer.

And the .Net installer gets stuck at the "downloading" step.

Is there any workaround for this? I'm on Lubuntu 20.04

```
$ wine --version
wine-4.0.4
```